# Best Practices for Handling Failures and Ensuring Data Consistency Across In-Memory DB, MongoDB, and Kafka in a Processing Pipeline

Tags: mongodb, apache-kafka, in-memory-database, consistency, idempotent

I'm architecting a service with a processing pipeline that updates an in-memory database, persists those updates in MongoDB, and finally produces messages to Kafka. My challenge is ensuring seamless recovery and data consistency when handling failures that may occur at various stages, specifically focusing on scenarios where re-consuming from Kafka is necessary for reprocessing.

**Process Overview:**

**In-Memory Database Update:** The service reads events from Kafka, updates records in an in-memory database based on the event data.
**MongoDB Persistence:** Subsequently, it persists these updates in MongoDB.
**Kafka Message Production:** After ensuring the updates are successfully persisted, it produces a new message to Kafka to signal the completion of processing.

**Challenges:**

**Failure between In-Memory DB and MongoDB:** There's a risk of inconsistency if the service crashes after updating the in-memory database but before the MongoDB persistence is completed. Upon recovery, the service needs to re-consume the original event from Kafka for reprocessing, which could lead to incorrectly calculated data.
**Failure between MongoDB and Kafka:** If a failure occurs after MongoDB persistence but before the Kafka message is produced, there's a risk of losing the indication that an event was processed, necessitating a re-consumption and reprocessing of the original Kafka event.

**Seeking Advice On:**

Strategies for Safe Re-consumption and Reprocessing: How can I ensure that re-consuming events from Kafka and reprocessing them does not lead to inconsistencies or incorrectly calculated data in both the in-memory database and MongoDB?
Idempotency Across the Pipeline: What are effective approaches to maintain idempotency across this multi-database setup, especially considering the need to potentially re-consume and reprocess events from Kafka?
Handling Transaction-Like Behavior: Considering the lack of a single transaction scope across the in-memory DB, MongoDB, and Kafka, are there patterns or mechanisms that can help emulate transactional integrity across these components?
I'm looking for insights or strategies that simplify handling these failure scenarios, enabling the system to recover gracefully without introducing excessive complexity or manual intervention.

Thank you in advance for your assistance and recommendations!

Comment: Your question is a bit too generic. Be aware the In-Memory MongoDB stores the data only in RAM, when the process dies than all data is gone.

Comment: It is supposed to be generic. I didn't mean to in-memory but to in-memory DB (like Redis etc.) @WernfriedDomscheit